# User Interface Specification

Tags: user-interface, user-controls, interface, specifications

I have Read this one [Graphical User Interface Specification Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398142/graphical-user-interface-specification-template)..

can you guide me more in this context?

Means i want to say that is there any practical process professional follows in real life to implement the user interface successfully .

Thank You
Mihir Parekh

Comment: Have you read the answers for this question?

Comment: but anyone give me some samples of user interface specification.so i can practicing on it.

Comment: i have been waiting for a long time for answer , but still did not get satisfactory answer from this great site.

Answer (score 1):

I liked Alan Cooper's book *About Face*.  Although my copy is a bit dated (I've got a first edition version), it had some great material. It's apparently now on the Fourth Edition (yikes, I bought my copy 19 years ago???), which you can get from Powell's (http://www.powells.com/biblio/1-9781118766576-0).  If you try getting it from Amazon, make sure it's the Fourth Edition, because when I searched on Alan Cooper it brought back the Third Edition at the top of the result list (at first I thought "Wow, that's a lot cheaper" until I realized it was not the latest version).

Oh, one other thing about Cooper - he can be entertaining as a writer.  One of his books (also definitely worth buying), *The Inmates are Running the Asylum*, is about usability, user experience, and product design in general and IIRC has some sections that are quite funny.

Also, do a web search for "user experience process".  One site that caught my eye was the UX Mastery site (http://uxmastery.com/).  I didn't really go too deeply into their site, but they've got a 'Resources' section that lists a ton of books that you might find useful (it depends on what kind of user interface requirements your app has, but it's a pretty broad selection).   Also in the 'Resources' section is a section covering process topics.